# PHP - URL Issue

Tags: php, url

i can't figure out what is the issue. Here is the pictures

```
https://www.website.com/index.php
```

I works good as you can see below.

[image]

But once if i type /index.php/index.php or /index.php/{any characters}. For example

```
https://www.website.com/index.php/popooopii2323**
```

[image]

How can i fix this, this is not only issue with index.php, even if login and goto dashboard or any other page within the UCP, i face this issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks you!

Comment: How do you insert your image (code)?

Comment: @Jax-p  i have an img in my website folder. This issue is not only with index.php, it's also can be done in dashboard.php/{any value} or any other page in my ucp and i get the same results... as what happened in index.php

Comment: Also, how is your url rewriting setup for the server end (apache? htaccess?). You need to provide more details for anyone to help you out.

Comment: Not completly sure from your question what your issue is?? Is it that your css is not working in some pages?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Hi, i have .htaccess in my root folder but it's empty.

Comment: Probably you're using relative paths, therefore the css and the background picture won't work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi, css is working good, this issue occurs only when i type "  anypage.php/ some value*.

Comment: @klediooo my .htcaccess file is empty.

Comment: Since you won't provide any actual code for us to see, here is the complete stab in the dark: Use absolute url-bound paths for including css/images in html. Do not use relative paths based on current url location.

Answer (score 0):

[Note: It would have been better if you could share some code segment from index.php file. I am just assuming your problem. It may or may not solve your issue. Anyway try this.]

The problem I'm guessing is with your path to **.css** file. Try to change you **.css** file path as following in your **index.php** file:
(Assuming, your path to **.css** file is *{project_root}/public/path/to/style.css*)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.website.com/path/to/style.css">
```

[P.S.]: Also, change your background image path as *https://www.website.com/path/to/bg_image.png*

Answer (score 0):

try to first put css file in head part of html. Please notice the link starting with abosolute path /.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

In that file, set background with relative path

```
.myBackground { background: url('../img/bg.jpg'); }
```

Then put style.css into folder css. And image into folder img.